# Date Difference Calculation Issue In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using the below method to get the date difference between two dates.

```
var MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
function dateDiffInDays(dateFrom, dateTo) {
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(dateFrom.getFullYear(), dateFrom.getMonth(), dateFrom.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(dateTo.getFullYear(), dateTo.getMonth(), dateTo.getDate());
  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / MS_PER_DAY);
}
```

If I give the dates as `01-01-2013` and `01-02-2013` it is returning `28` which is wrong,
expected answer is `31`. But for all other cases that I have tested it gave me correct answer.

What should I do to get this work correctly?

DownVoters: Please Comment Reason.

Comment: might be something with your local settings or the way you instantiate your Dates (note that getMonth returns zero based indexes) You should use a library like http://momentjs.com/ to handle Date manipulations.

Comment: @jbl So does that mean I can't get this piece of code work correctly?

Comment: Sure you can. I guess that this part works, but also that your inputs are not what you think they are. Pay attention on how you build  your dateFrom and dateTo. They are not what you think. And make more tests. Anyway, using a library will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Javascripts Date()s Month is 0 based. So you are calculating the difference between February 1st and March 1st. Therefore the right result here is 28.

What you wanted to achieve I guess was the difference between January 1st and February 1st.

So you have to Check where the Dates dateFrom and dateTo are set and there change the Month to Month - 1.

Here's an example:

```
var fromDate = new Date(2013,1,1,0,0,0);
var toDate = new Date(2013,2,1,0,0,0);

var MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
function dateDiffInDays(dateFrom, dateTo) {
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(dateFrom.getFullYear(), dateFrom.getMonth(), dateFrom.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(dateTo.getFullYear(), dateTo.getMonth(), dateTo.getDate());
  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / MS_PER_DAY);
}
```

this will return 28 Days correctly, because you set fromDate to February 1st and toDate to March 1st.

0 Based means when you create a new Date you have to write for the Months:

January 0
February 1
March 2
.
.
.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get the solution for the problem.

Comment: Can you post your code where fromDate and toDate are initialised pls?

Comment: it seems it parses the date by using a already downloaded js file. It contains too many lines, so posting it would not be good. Thanks for helping me to find the issue.